# TLSharp propper log out

Tags: c#, winforms, telegram

I am trying to add some telegram functions to my winForm app. I am using TLSharp library for that. However there is no proper manual on how to logout from the account. Everything I found on forums led to this:

```
var LogOut = new TLRequestLogOut();
await MainWindow.client.SendRequestAsync<Boolean>(LogOut);
```

That does log out but, 1st - It gives an Exception error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Couldn't read the packet length at TLSharp.Core.Network.TcpTransport.<Receieve>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

2nd - The "IsUserAuthorized" still return true after logout request.
3rd - session file, even being deleted with

```
File.Delete(sessionName);
```

restores itself